# Reasonable to be nervous when updating kernel packages?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

Everytime I run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and the results include:

- `linux-headers-*`, `linux-modules-*`, etc., and/or
- `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-*`, etc.

I get nervous that something will go wrong and my machine will be unusable (at least temporarily), especially if the boot is funked. Maybe my fears are rooted in the [windows dual-boot-wipe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384) rite of passage.

Is this reasonable? Can someone allay my fears and let me upgrade in peace?

Comment: Sorry if this is off-topic, but I can't be the only one...!

Comment: If an issue occurs with the new kernel - rare, but it has happened - you can use the grub screen to boot into the previous kernel.  So, no worries.

Comment: Until I remove them, right? Like `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required` -- I always wait a few boot cycles before removing any `linux-*` packages, for this reason

Comment: The newest-but-one kernel will not be automatically removed. Older ones will be.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe.
Not only do you have the previous version to fall back on at GRUB, you have recovery mode for both.
For what it is worth I use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo snap refresh` although you can split our the auto remove and auto clean. I also have my system set to delete the package files once installed as I use `apt-cacher-ng`  on a local server to hold all of these and share across multiple devices reducing bandwidth and install times.